# WPF ComboBox GotFocus

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DataGrid` with a `ComboBox` column and I need to add items to that combobox only when it get focus. I handle the event `GotFocus`, but still have a problem. In fact once I select an item from the dropdown the event will fire again. Any workaround on how to fix this issue.

```
private void CmbxGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() != typeof(ComboBoxItem) && !this.returnedFocus)
    {
        //dowork
    }
}

private void CmbxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() != typeof(ComboBoxItem))
    {
        ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;           

        if (cb != null)
        {
            this.returnedFocus = cb.IsDropDownOpen;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried DropDownClosed?

Comment: if (combo1.Focused && combo1.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
         ...
    }

Comment: the current combobox is inside a datagrid datatemplate so we cannot access it directly

Comment: You need to use an editing template on your column.